# Disconnecting from Minecraft server with good connection

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

My friend has hosted a Minecraft server on Shockbyte but I cannot connect.

I have a decent internet connection. I have on average 137ms ping to the server, 43Mbps download and 10Mbps upload.

I'm getting error messages such as:

> java
> java.net.socketException:
> Connection Reset Timed Out

All my friends can smoothly play on the server but I can't. I'm playing on 1.18.1 and my Java is the newest. I have also forwarded the port 25565 on my firewall but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: This may seem stupid but you could try resetting the game, your computer, or uninstall and reinstall the game.

Comment: I have this issue too. I'm using a hetzner server. All other servers are fine. A big difference is that my internet is totally pathetic.

Answer (score 2):

Is that server's properties can be edited? if so, maybe change the `view-distance`(it basically defines how many chunks are sent to the player) to 12 or something lower. The issue basically falls in that clients have X(time it takes to timeout) amount of time to connect. Problem is, that includes processing all of the chunks on player's end.

The issue could perhaps be your PC's spec, internet connection(that internet connection is not so "good" apparently), or something else - so, setting the view distance lower would take care of both problems, sacrificing a bit of draw distance, which most of time doesn't really matter, except when you're flying with Elytra.

Answer (score 0):

1. Edit your network adaptor.
2. Go to Advanced and look for speed/link.
3. If this is set to Auto, that is your problem. Change it to highest speed full duplex.

Also you may want to check power saving options as well and turn those off. What the link speed does in Minecraft is when your network adaptor changes it's link speed it disconnects you from the network for a few seconds. This is enough to make you disconnect from the server.